# htaccess to mask a url with multiple rules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this htaccess file in the root folder.

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/squash_test/find_a_player
    #RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost/squash_test/home/find_a_player [P]

    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is working all good.
What i want is, keeping the existing functionality, i would like to mask two urls.

If i visit

```
http://localhost/squash_test/find_a_player
```

then it should display the content from

```
http://localhost/squash_test/home/find_a_player
```

Similarly i have another url, which needs such masking. I tried to search across the internet and i did get few solutions but none of them correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is it the single URL `/squash_test/find_a_player` you need to route into `squash_test/home/find_a_player` or multiple URLs in the `squash_test/` path?  Rewrite rules are highly order-dependent. This more specific rule would need to be placed before your very general `RewriteRule ^(.*)`

Comment: I have written in my question that i have to mask two urls. the one you mentioned and another url, similar type.

Comment: I understand, but with _similar type_, you need to be more specific. As  I asked, is the other URL in the same path to the same target directory?

Comment: Yes, instead of find_a_player, its find_a_club. Rest all remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(squash_test)/(find_a_player)/?$ /$1/home/$2 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser? Is it `http://example.com/squash_test/find_a_player`? Also is `/squash_test/` a real directory?

Comment: I inputed http://localhost/squash_test/find_a_player and yes, squash_test is a real directory.

Comment: Do you have .htaccess inside `/squash_test/` also? Are there more rules in root .htaccess?

Comment: Bravo !! I changed the rule to RewriteRule ^(find_a_player)/?$ home/$1 [L,NC] and it worked like a charm. Thank you so much.